# addTarget method on UIButton Class reference document

Tags: iphone, ios, class, reference, uibutton

why I dont see the addTarget method:

`[button addTarget:(id) action:(SEL) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)]`

on UIButton Class reference document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an inherited method of UIControl